# I'm confused about a segment of an R for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm working on modifying an existing R script and I'm basically picking R up while learning it. I don't have a strong programming background (I'm learning) and so I'm hoping that someone can simply help explain a part of this for loop. (Note this is using ggplot2 among some other packages)

```
files <- unique(SQLTable$file_names)
for (i in 1:3){
    dat <- subset(SQLTable,file_names==files[])
    g <- ggplot(dat) + geom_point(aes(x = id, y = Value), size = 1, shape = 19, colour = 'red') + 
        geom_line(aes(x = id, y = Value), size =.5) + 
        facet_grid(Measure ~., scales = "free")
    print(g)
}
```

Don't worry about SQLTable, file_names, id, or Value, those are all either a SQL table or column names. The code above is a part of a larger script but I'm trying to figure out what the (i in 1:3) is doing in the for loop. I pretty much get everything else thats going on in the loop but I've modified it to be (i in 1:2) all the way to (i in 1:100) and it doesn't seem to make much of a change. So whats the purpose? Why is it specifically 1:3? I hope that doesn't rely on other things but if it does, maybe you can just explain what that part is doing?

**EDIT:** When I run that section of code, I get the following message 6 times.
`geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`

followed by

```
Warning messages: 
1: In File_names == secnarios[]:
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In File_names == secnarios[]:
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In File_names == secnarios[]:
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

When I run the code with `file_names==files[i]` then I get this:

```
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
Warning messages:
1: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
2: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
3: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
4: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

Comment: I don't see `i` inside the loop and hence the expected behavior.

Comment: You probably meant to have `file_names==files[i]` so that it would generate a different plot for each set of files. Right now it does the exact same plot three times in a row.

Comment: maybe it should have but its not set up like that. Is there any reason for it to be set up without the `i`?

Comment: You need a `i` within the sequence. Neal Fultz is certainly right

Comment: I added the warning messages given when running the code. They do seem to fit that but it seems strange that I can run it at all without an `i`.

Comment: Also, wouldn't 1:3 imply there would only be 3 files looped over?

Comment: You are asking us to help without letting us know the structure of data. Please provide sample data.

Comment: I'm not asking for help with setting up the loop or building charts. I'm simply asking what `(i in *vector*)` does. The data is irrelevant.

Comment: @David it does not imply anything. You are looping over the vector `c(1, 2, 3)`. The rest is up to you, the programmer, to specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `i` in the loop itself, this just repeats whatever is in `{ ... }` three times. You're just recalculating everything and overwriting the same variable three times, or in your case 100. That's why it doesn't change anything.

You get the error 6 times because, each iteration, you're causing two problems.

Comment: So I'm guessing there's not really a good reason to do this intentionally? Since `file_names` comes from a SQL table, shouldn't the `(i in 1:3)` reflect how many unique `file_names` there are? Say I have 20 different files, shouldn't it be `(i in 1:20)`?

Comment: @David as written, it doesn't matter because `i` doesn't show up in the loop

Comment: Thats not my question. I'm curious 1. If there would be any reason to intentionally write this loop without including i and then 2. once i is included in the loop does the (i in 1:3) represent how many unique `file_names` there are?

Comment: @David that wasn't clear at all. Answer to 1: maybe, but I don't see one here. Answer to 2: no. on the first iteration of `for (index in vec)` assigns `index <- vec[[1]]` and executes the contents of the loop. on the second iteration, it assigns `index <- vec[[2]]` and executes the contents of the loop with the new value of `index`. This continues up to and including `index <- vec[[length(vec)]]` at which point the loop exits. In this case, you have `for (i in 1:3)` so it executes the loop with `i <-1` then `i <- 2` then `i <- 3` then exits. `1:3` doesn't "represent" anything other than `1:3`

Comment: If you _want_ it to "represent" the indices of `files` you should write `for (i in 1:length(files))` or `for (i in seq_along(files))`.

Comment: Right now, I'm just trying to follow the original author's intent. I'm still not understanding (as I said I'm still learning). What is `i` then? Perhaps there isn't enough info from my question to answer that but what is `i`? Simply the count of the loop?

Comment: @David the original author was clearly confused. Hence the comments on the original question an your own confusion in trying to follow the code